# Java regex - why did the Matcher find extra characters?

Tags: java, regex

I was experimenting trying to extract the 't' and 'f' flags from here.
So I was surprised to see extra characters in the output. Apparently the matcher backtracked - I dont understand why. What should be the correct regex?

```
    System.out.println("searching...");
    // "Sun:\\s Mon:\\s Tue:\\s Wed:\\s Thu:\\s Fri:\\s Sat:\\s "
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[t|f]");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("Sun:t Mon:f Tue:t Wed:t Thu:f Fri:t Sat:f ");
    while (m.find()) {
      System.out.println(m.group());
    }
```

Output:

```
searching...
t
f
t
t
f
t
t
f
```

Comment: Please note that the pattern `[t|f]` will match any of **three** characters: `'t'`, `'f'`, or `'|'`.  If you don't want to match the vertical bar then remove it.  `|` does not mean "or" here.  Special characters usually do *not* mean the same thing inside `[]` that they do in the rest of the pattern.

Comment: @ajb `[t|f] will match any of three characters: 't', 'f', or '|'` that is useful to know. thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Sat` has a `t` in it.  Try `":([tf])"` instead.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(":([tf])");
Matcher m = p.matcher("Sun:t Mon:f Tue:t Wed:t Thu:f Fri:t Sat:f ");
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Comment: Hilarious! I did not see that and hastily assumed it backtracked. That worked. :D Does the () specify that only t and f are in the capturing group?

Comment: @likejiujitsu Yes, if you have multiple `()` you can get each portion as a different group.